# Comma separated list from checkbox values

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I've been digging around to try and get a list of comma separated values from a set of checkboxes. There have been lots of useful answers here, but I can't work out a final kink. My code is behaving oddly depending on whether or not the first checkbox is checked and I can't work out why (this is my first ever attempt at javascript!)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateTextArea() {
        var allVals = $('input.gift:checked').map( 
        function() {return this.value;}).get().join();

        $('#txtValue').val(allVals)
    }
    $(function () {
        $('#gift input').click(updateTextArea);
        updateTextArea();
    });
</script>
```

And here's the html that accompanies it.

```
<fieldset id="gift">
    <input type='checkbox' name='lFreeProductid' value='8840'
        id="lFreeProductid1" class="gift">
    </td>
    <td class="style42">64 SSG</td>
    <td class="style32">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


    <tr id="tr2">
        <td class="style33"><input type='checkbox' name='lFreeProductid'
            value='420' id="lFreeProductid1" class="gift"></td>
        <td class="style41">Perfect D</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


    <tr id="tr3">
        <td class="style33"><input type='checkbox' name='lFreeProductid'
            value='460' id="lFreeProductid1" class="gift"></td>
        <td class="style41">Soccer Attack</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</fieldset>

<tr>
    <td class="style33">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="style41">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>


<textarea id="txtValue"></textarea>
```

I know this is the sort of question that's been asked a thousand times, but I can't seem to find a solution to this specific issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what might be causing an odd behaviour of the checkboxes is the same id you are setting for each of them

Comment: the provided html markup is invalid and is missing tags

Comment: First of all, your html doesn't look correct and as tratto said, id's should be same for any 2 elements.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the IDs to be unique. Tratto, do you mean the tags for the start of the table etc? Or other tags related to the inputs?

Comment: oh, I think I got it. I don't think the fieldset was wrapping around correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is working fine !

Check this demo once : https://jsbin.com/vigixi/46/edit?html,js,output

And if this is not the desired output you want. Then let us know what exactly you want.

Comment: Thanks KrishCdbry. Yes, looks like it was all fine other than my fieldset. Your code removed the fieldset and put the id in the table which resolved the problem!

Comment: Most welcome buddy !  It my chages helps mark it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to correct all the HTML syntax errors

```
<fieldset id="gift">
  <table>
    <tr id="tr1">
      <td class="style33"><input type='checkbox' name='lFreeProductid' value='8840' id="lFreeProductid1"  class="gift"></td>
      <td class="style42"><label for="lFreeProductid1">64 SSG</label></td>
      <td class="style32">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


    <tr id="tr2">
      <td class="style33"><input type='checkbox' name='lFreeProductid' value='420' id="lFreeProductid2"  class="gift"></td>
      <td class="style41"><label for="lFreeProductid2">Perfect D</label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


    <tr id="tr3">
      <td class="style33"><input type='checkbox' name='lFreeProductid' value='460' id="lFreeProductid3" class="gift"></td>
      <td class="style41"><label for="lFreeProductid3">Soccer Attack</label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="style33">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="style41">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset> 
<textarea id="txtValue"></textarea>
```

Your issue could be due to a certain browser or/and doctype